# Django syncdb command, can't find column in table it's creating

Tags: sql, django, django-models, sqlite

I've decided to restart my database over from scratch after it get very messy. so I dropped the database and am now trying to recreate it with syncdb. as you can see below it's creating the table timber_management, where it falls over because it can't find timber_uuid inside timber management. But, it's not made timber management yet so I'm rather confused.

```
Creating table timber_measurement
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 99, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 200, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: table timber_measurement has no column named timber_uuid
```

Django Model:

```
class TimberMeasurement(models.Model):
    uuid              = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    timber            = models.ForeignKey(Timber, db_column='timber_uuid',null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    measurement_value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    measurement_type  = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=MEASUREMENT_TYPE, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'boughtin'
        db_table = 'timber_measurement'
        unique_together = ('timber', 'measurement_value', 'measurement_type')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running a fresh syncdb, it seems to be a requirement to do the following

```
#unique_together = ('timber', 'measurement_value', 'measurement_type')
```